# How to store document vectors in a database for a search engine?

Tags: database, search-engine, information-retrieval

I have implemented a search engine in Java. It has a database that stores the inverted index ie mapping from terms to list of documents the term appears in. There is a feature that allows a user to upload a document which can be added to document for indexing. The problem that i'm facing is that , everytime a new document is added , the index is reconstructed in memory instead of being updated . To update , i would need a database that stores document vectors that are essentially tf-idf's(term frequency* inverse document frequency) of each and every term in the index. I'm not able to work out database structure for it as in what rows and columns or multiple tables would be needed for storing such a structure.

I need to store

```
1. Document ID 
2. Document Title
3. N dimensional Document vector where N is the number of unique terms
4. N terms 
5. IDF of each term
6. TF of each term for every document.
```

I need it so that at the time of query matching i can extract this vector and calculate its similarity with the query vector.If you want any additional information, please let me know.
Thank you very much , I'm sure i would get some help here.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? How did you end up storing the document vectors?

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure you wanna use a Database to implement a search engine?

You may take a look at this Java framework which does an excellent job and very simple to learn .

[Lucene Tutorial in 5 mins](http://www.lucenetutorial.com/lucene-in-5-minutes.html)

It uses the Vector Space Model and there's no need for you to worry about all the above fields you mentioned in your post, since Lucene stores them along with much more advanced ranking factors.

I am sorry that my reply doesn't help you if you are intentionally using the Databases.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your reply !Actually i have intentionally not used lucene since i wanted to make a search engine. Well, as a matter of fact , although i have decided on the database tables and structure, i'm not having much luck since,, it has to form vectors again by reading the database (and it's taking forever to do that) whenever a new file is uploaded. :\